# numpy how can i get the value of an element at certain coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have found ways of getting the maximum value of a numpy array, and then getting the coordinates, but is there any way of doing the opposite?

I mean, getting the value of an array element by inputting 2D coordinates?

Would really appreciate the help!

Cheers,

David

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `A[row_number,column_number]`

The first row or column is numbered 0.

Here is an example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [4]: A[1,1]
Out[4]: 5

In [5]: A[2,1]
Out[5]: 8

In [6]: A[0,1]
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: A[2,2]
Out[7]: 9
```

And you can also use tuples for coordinates:

```
In [8]: coords = (0,0)

In [9]: A[coords]
Out[9]: 1

In [10]: newcoords = (2,2)

In [11]: A[newcoords]
Out[11]: 9
```

There are several other ways to read the elements of a numpy array.  You may wish to read this [Indexing documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)